How to find a Fourier series using trig identities
How to find the Fourier series of
$$f(x) = \sin^3 (x) - \cos^3 (x) + \cos^4 (x)$$
My professor said we won't need to solve integrals but I am not sure why ?
I am confused why we won't find the Fourier series coefficients $a_0$, $a_n$, $b_n$.
Also I tried to simplify the terms using trig identities.
$$\sin^3 (x) = 3/4 \sin(x)- 1/4 \sin(3x)$$
$$\cos^3(x) = 1/4 \cos(3x) + 3/4 \cos (x)$$
$$\cos^4 (x) = [(\cos2x +1)/2]^2$$

Hint: Think about if you can express the three terms in a different way.... Please edit the problem to include some efforts if you would like further help.

At first I tried the problem using the Fourier series formula and focused on finding the coefficients but the problem was very long and the integral confused me.

Your efforts that you have edited in are good. In fact, there  is a similar expansion for $\cos^4(x)$ that you may find useful https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Reduction_Formulas/Cosine_to_4th.  Do you see what to do from there?

You have already solved the problem, $f(x)=-\sin(3x)/4+3\sin(x)/4-\cos(3x)/4-3\cos(x)/4+\cos(4x)/8 +\cos(2x)/2+3/8$ ''is'' the Fourier series. You may rewrite this in complex form with Euler's relations, but that does not actually mean much.

You've done a great job so far and are on exactly the right path.

thank you so much. I just had one question for this why aren't we finding the coefficients and then substituting them in the Fourier series formula.

You did find the coefficients which are something like $$a(n)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{3}{8} & n=0 \
-\frac{3}{4} & n=1 \
\frac{1}{2} & n=2 \
-\frac{1}{4} & n=3 \
\frac{1}{8} & n=4 \
0 & \text{otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.$$ and $$b(n)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{3}{4} & n=1 \
-\frac{1}{4} & n=3 \
0 & \text{otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.$$ where $$f(x)=a(0)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n), \cos(n x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b(n), \sin(n x).$$
